# Laravel Webpack Build for jQuery, AdminLTE and Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, laravel, npm, webpack

Apologies for the long post, I've been trying not to give up on this one, but I've had to admit... I've been out of the game too long (a lot of hospital time), and I'm not winning.

I had an app built on Laravel using Webpack (about four years ago), and everything ran great. Now I'm trying to update. I don't want to use CDNs so I can work offline, but my Webpack build just isn't happening.

JQuery doesn't want to build. However, I've checked the build, and it's there, so I'm doing something wrong.

So for Webpack, I have (a bit of a cut-down version, but this is what I'm trying to build):

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
let productionSourceMaps = true;

let preCompiled = {
   node: 'node_modules/',
   jquery: 'node_modules/jquery/dist/',
   jquery_ui: 'node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/',
   bootstrap: 'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/',
   app: 'resources/assets/app/',
};

let compiled = {
   app: 'public/assets/app/'
};

// App Pages
mix.js([
    preCompiled.node+'admin-lte/dist/js/adminlte.js',
    preCompiled.jquery+'jquery.js',
    preCompiled.jquery_ui+'jquery-ui.js',
    preCompiled.bootstrap+'js/bootstrap.bundle.js',
], compiled.app+'js/app.js');

mix.copy(preCompiled.node+'admin-lte/dist/img/', compiled.app+'img/');


mix.webpackConfig({
    stats: {
        children: true,
    },
});

mix.version();
```

The problem is I keep getting

> TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...jQuery...')

I've tested with a build including only jQuery, and it's building jQuery in my js/app.js file. I've tried re-ordering the build components but no joy. It's me, and not up to scratch, but I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: In order for me to reproduce the problem I need the pice of code that generates `TypeError: undefined is not a function`, in other words, there's some jquery somewhere, maybe some adminlte html and when you look at it, you see that error. I need that piece of html/jquery to reproduce what you're having. In your `mix.copy` function, you call for compiled.simplifi`, but that's not in your compiled{} object (?), might be a tiny oversight, because you simplified your webpack file

Comment: Thanks! Just a small portion of it but according to the console output it's getting stuck at the first line:

`jQuery(function(){
   $('.clickable-row').on('click', 'td:not(.no-click)', function(){
        var href = $(this).parent().attr('href');
        document.location=href;
    });
});`

Comment: Ok, I'll try to reproduce it when I have time. Which version of adminlte are you using? Version 3?

Comment: Apologies for the badly formatted code above. Also I forgot to change "simplifi" to "app" for the purposes of posting. "Simplifi" is my admin area but the only one that uses AdminLTE. 

Thanks Again

Comment: Currently I'm on `"admin-lte": "^3.2.0"`

Comment: The odd thing is that with the CDN it works just fine it's only the build. So I thought I'd do a separate build for just jquery and call that before my app.js - still no joy.

I just can't think what the CDN is doing differently.

Comment: I don't have time to reproduce it, for a couple of days. I'm thinking: maybe it's the order in which you add the javascript packages to your mix.js function. I firstly see adminlte and then the jquery, maybe switch the order?

Comment: This however seems to work fine!? 

Not the work around I wanted but I guess it works...

`mix.copy(preCompiled.jquery+'jquery.js', compiled.app + 'js/');`

Then just include it as I would the CDN so something's funny with the webpack I guess?

Comment: I would go with that for now. I know you wanted to work/revive your old project, but there are lots of other great admin templates out there than adminlte. Adminlte is soooo 1990. Just my opinion. I recommend coreui or I recommend looking into tailwind, just for the kicks of it